# Count occurences of strings in column - Matlab

Tags: matlab, unique, accumarray

I have a column with the following data:
Size: 100x7

```
val =

USA
USA
France
USA
France
```

I want to show the data on pie chart. to do this, I need to know how much USA occur in this column, and so on.
I read about the functions unique,accumarray but I dont success
I would like to get some suggestions how to do that.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unique` with `histc` -

```
%// Get countries and their occurences
[countries,~,id] = unique(cellstr(val),'stable')
occurrences = histc(id,1:max(id))
```

You can then display the number of occurrences against the country names **as a table** -

```
>> table(countries,occurrences)
ans = 
    countries    occurrences
    _________    ___________
    'USA'        3          
    'France'     2
```

Display output **as a pie chart** -

```
>> pie(occurrences,countries)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know about pie.  This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Googling helps these days! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and make sure that those input strings are in a `cell` array.  The third output of `unique` is pretty cool, because it assigns a unique ID for each unique quantity that is seen in the input.  As such, if you had a sequence of characters from `a` to `e`, it would assign a unique ID for each unique character that it has found, between 1 and 5.  Also, the first output of `unique` gives you an array that only contains the unique quantities seen in the input.

You can then use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) on this third output to count how many times you see a particular country over all countries listed.

```
val = {'USA'; 'USA'; 'France'; 'USA'; 'France'};
[countries,~,id] = unique(val);
counts = accumarray(id, 1);
```

I get:

```
counts = 

2 
3
```

Also for `countries`:

```
countries = 

    'France'
    'USA'
```

Notice that each element of `counts` corresponds to how many times you see that particular country in the same position as the country in `countries`, so France is seen 2 times, and USA 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of occurrences by using regexp:

```
unique_countries = unique(regexp(val,'^.*$','lineanchors','match','dotexceptnewline'));

count_unique_countries = zeros(size(unique_countries));
for ii = 1:numel(unique_countries)
    count_unique_countries(ii) = numel(regexp(val,['^' unique_countries{ii} '$'],'lineanchors'));
end
```

The two output variables are now

```
unique_countries = 
'France'    'USA'
count_unique_countries =
 1     2
```

Comment: This only finds one country.  The question is asking to find all countries.

Comment: To make this work for all of the countries, perhaps find all of the unique countries in the list, then use `regexp` and loop over each unique country, but the efficiency of that is questionable compared to `unique` with `hist/accumarray`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited solution to find number of occurrences for all countries. As you mention it will first find the unique countries with a combination of unique and regexp.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the statistics toolbox, you can also do the following:

```
valnom = nominal(val);
countries = getlabels(valnom);
occurrences = levelcounts(valnom);
```