# Determining the number of occurrences of each word in cell array

Tags: matlab, text, word-frequency

I have huge vector of words, and I want a vector with the unique words only, and the frequency for each word. I've already tried `hist` and `histc` but they are for numeric value. 
I know the function `tabulate` but it gives the words some ' (e.g this turns to 'this'). 
If you have any idea how to do it MATLAB it would be great. thanks

Comment: For the 1st part have you tried 'unique'? It works with cell arrays of strings

Comment: Yes, unique works. but, what is the next step? I thought about loop which count every word, but I guess there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track! Just use `unique` first to prepare the numeric input for `hist`. The trick is that the word occurence ids returned by `unique` can be used as input for the `hist` function, so you can get the counts without explicit `for` loops:

```
words = {'abba' 'bed' 'carrot' 'damage' 'bed'};
[unique_words, ~, occurrences] = unique(words);
unique_counts = hist(occurrences, 1:max(occurrences));
```

This yields:

```
>> unique_words 
    'abba'    'bed'    'carrot'    'damage'

>> unique_counts
     1     2     1     1
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get this error: Error using histc
Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.

Error in hist (line 119)
    nn = histc(y,edgesc,1);

Comment: Apparently not in the same way: I don't use `histc`, and the `word_ids` are - depending on your MATLAB version - already the monotonically increasing range from 1 to number of unique words.

Comment: @Yaeli778 `histc(id_positions_in_word_vector, 1:max(id_positions_in_word_vector));` might do it. Source - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27281656/3293881