# Iterating Over Unique Values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, brackets, curly-braces, word-frequency

I've been trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27488429/1692226) in order to obtain unique strings from a given cell array. However, I'm running into trouble when iterating over these values. I have tried for loops as follows:

```
[unique_words, ~, occurrences] = unique(words);
unique_counts = hist(occurrences, 1:max(occurrences));

for a=1:numel(unique_words)
  word = unique_words{a}
  count = unique_counts{a}
  result = result + a_struct.(unique_words{a}) + unique_counts{a}
end
```

When trying to reference the items like this, I receive the error:

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Changing the curly brackets to round brackets for `unique_couts` yields the error:

> Reference to non-existent field 'N1'.

Changing both `unique_words` and `unique_counts` to round brackets yields:

> Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.

How am I to iterate over the results of unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_words` is a cell array. `unique_counts` is a vector. So `unique_words` should be accessed using curly brackets and `unique_counts` using round ones. The error that you are getting in this case is related to the `a_struct` (which is not defined in the question) not having the corresponding field, not the access method.